# Full screen in gnome desktop similar to i3-wm?

Tags: gnome, gnome3, desktop-environment, gnome-shell, fullscreen

I used tiling window manager and I like two things that is tiling and full screen mode.

By using pop shell in gnome, I got the tiling but I didn't find any resources for full screen such that no panel will be show. I want similar full screen in every app like in i3-wm. Mostly commonly this type of full screen is supported by application like browser, presentation and pdf reader software.

How can I have presentation mode for any app where panel will hide in full screen in gnome similar to i3-wm?

Note: I am using Fedora Silver Blue with gnome 4+